# How to check if a PHP object has a property in PHP4.

Tags: php, php4

I would like to check if a PHP object has a property. For PHP5 I could use

```
if (property_exists($object, "foo")) {...}
```

but how can I do the same in PHP4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `get_object_vars` and check the resulting array if your property exists.

Please refer to the the documentation on `get_object_vars` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Comment: In the same vein: `$obj_arr = (array)$object; print isset($obj_arr["foo"]);`

Answer (score 3):

```
/***
Just as you would do for PHP5, you can apply the same concept for PHP 4. 

***/
//$data is a JSON object am receiving from a  server.
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['data']));

/****
Applying the same property_exists method but remember to keep both object/class    
and the property to check for in single quotes.
*****/
if (property_exists('data', 'content')) 
{

$content = $data->content;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for information about how to write a good answer.